# Netbeans 7.4 with pyflakes

Tags: python, netbeans-7, pep8, pyflakes, flake8

I installed a plugin for NetBeans 7.4 to make Python work, and it does.

But now I am racking my brains to manage another plugin for same IDE which includes pyflakes (PEP 8 and flake8).

I am starting to think that for the moment it just does not exist. Am I right?

Thank you in advance.